Getting warning when declaring static computed property in class
I've enabled Complete Strict Concurrency Checking in my project and there's warning telling me that Static property 'computedProperty' is not concurrency-safe because non-'Sendable' type '() -> String' may have shared mutable state; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode.
Here's the sample code how I get this warning:
class TestClass {
    static let computedProperty: () -> String = {
        return "Testing"
    }
}

Can anyone explain why I get this warning and the reason behind?
Removing static annotation or making it as a static function can solve the warning, but why?
static func staticFunc() -> String {
    return "Testing"
}


As the duplicate says, it is safe if the closure is sendable, which you can declare as static let computedProperty: @Sendable () -> String = ....

@Sweeper So, for every closure, we have to add @Sendable even though all its types are thread-safe?

Note that I am not marking the closure as @Sendable in my comment, which would have been { @Sendable in ... }. I am marking the type of computedProperty as @Sendable. Then, Swift is able to infer that the closure on the right of the =  should be sendable too. So there is a little bit of inference. But yeah, you need to do this for every property of a function type.

Also, I should point out that the parameter types and return type of the closure being sendable is not sufficient for the closure to be sendable. The closure must not capture any non-sendable values, among other things. See https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0302-concurrent-value-and-concurrent-closures.md#new-sendable-attribute-for-functions for more info.

@Sweeper Thanks for your explanation, it's really helpful.
